# Deleting deleted log files (/var/log/daemon.log (deleted))

Tags: debian, logs

I currently have a Debian server that is running out of hard drive space and by using the `lsof | grep deleted | less` command I have found the offending files that have used up (but not freed up) space.

```
in:imklog   462   518             root    7w      REG                8,1 11199498620    1448243 /var/log/daemon.log (deleted)
```

I know that rebooting will 99.999% release these files, but this is not desirable.

I appreciate that deleting the files (instead of a `logrotate`) has resulted in this situation, so will address this BUT, my question is, can I release these files being held up and not freeing up space without a reboot? And is yes, how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reload/Restart or send a `HUP` signal (`kill -1`) to whatever's holding the log files open (probably `rsyslogd`).   You're probably running systemd, so that's:

```
systemctl restart rsyslog.service
```

or `/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart` if you're running `sysvinit`.

This will cause rsyslogd to reload its config file(s), close and re-open all of its log files.

(note: with most daemons, "reload" is the keyword to use to get them to reload their config files and/or close & re-open any files, and "restart" is used to stop and then start it.  For some reason, "restart" is used with the debian rsyslog packages to trigger a reload by sending a HUP signal to the rsyslog daemon)

As soon as there is no process remaining with an open file handle to that log file, the space it is using will be freed.

Comment: `/etc/init.d/rsyslog reload` didn't work, for me (`Failed to reload rsyslog.service: Job type reload is not applicable for unit rsyslog.service.`) but `/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart` did the trick, thanks!

Comment: how odd, "restart" usually means "stop. then start.", while "reload" means send a signal or do whatever to cause the daemon to reload its config files and/or close & re-open its log files.   looks like that's not the case with rsyslog (but if you run `systemctl status rsyslog`, the log entry will still say "....rsyslogd was HUPed" after a "restart").  i'll update the answer.